# How to view WordPress' default category IDs?

Tags: categories, taxonomy, id, customization, documentation

It seems that Wordpress has default categories with default (and unchangeable) IDs. For example, the `uncategorized` category seems to always have an id of `1`. Is this always the case? Is there any official documentation for this (and other default category IDs)?

**Question (big picture)**

How to view a list of these default categories and ids?

**Question (contextual)**

I'm using `get_terms` to view a list of categories for post filtering. `unpublished` is being returned as a category, though for obvious reasons it's not desirable (on a site's frontend) to filter posts by those not yet published, so I need to exclude it. I've figured out that at least on my particular Wordpress install the unpublished category ID is `50`. Is this always the case?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one default term in Wordpress, that is the term `uncategorized` from the taxonomy `category`. This term is created when Wordpress is first installed. This term's ID will always be `1` if it is not altered in any other way by some custom code from a custom theme or plugin.

Term ids, like post ids, are very reliable and does not change within a specific installation unless they are altered by their relevant `update_*` functions like [`wp_update_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_term) which is used to modify term field values of an already created term. Here the term id will change if the `term_id` field is explicitely set to anything else outside the original term id. Also, if a term is deleted, and it is recreeated, the term id will also differ from the previous one.

Term ids, like post ids, will differ between different installs ( except for the term `uncategorized`, and the "Hello World" post ) as ids are assigned numerically ascending order in the order the post or term is created. In one install, if a term with slug `term` is created as the seventh term, it will have an id of `7`, on another install, if the same term was created tenth, it will have an id of `10`.

To get a term id is easy, go to the categories page ( or tag or custom taxonomy pages), go to the specific term and keep your mouse on the `edit` link. In the bottom left there will be a grey block which will hold the term id amongs other info. You can also create an extra column in your backend taxonomy ( category, tag or custom taxonomy ) pages to display the term id. There are a couple of good tutorials about this subject. You can also do a `var_dump()` of the the result from functions like `get_terms()` to find the relevant info from a specific term

To conclude, term ids within a specific install should always be 99.999% reliable, a term id does not change, it stays the same unless it is altered by the user himself via custom SQL queries or a custom function capable of altering the term id field, a plugin or a theme using such functionalities or if a term is deleted and recreated